# Browser and initial activity issue

Tags: android

I'm having trouble when activity A call browser activity. Browser will parse url e when the user press back, i want the first activity will restart and not show blank page.
Here's the code

```
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    Integer id =getIntent().getExtras().getInt("id");

    Intent browserIntent;

    switch (id) { 
    case 1: 
        browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,Uri.parse("http:example"));
        startActivity(browserIntent);
            break;
   etc etc
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure I completely understand your goals but I will take my best shot.

When you start a new activity B and then finish it, activity A will follow the activity [lifecycle](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html).

It sounds like you want your code in onCreate to run after B finishes but onCreate is only called during activity initialization. Perhaps if you move your switch logic to onResume(), which will be called after Activity B finishes, you will get the result you want.

Comment: sorry i missed the code.updated. i want that when user on browser push back button, the main intent will reboot.

Comment: Follow my instruction with putting your logic other then setting up your content view into onResume(). That will get called after onCreate() and also after activities started after it are finished. Read the link about the android lifecycle I put in my answer to fully understand what happens when you show and finish activities.